# Angular Generate a PDF document from a DIV class in HTML

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an Invoicing app with angular.

Inside a DIV class, I have generated a preview of my Invoice.

I want to be able to generate a PDF file from this Div Class. Is it possible? Do you have any hint? What would another way?

Warms Regards
Mathieu

Comment: The best hint i can provide is to show what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

`jsPDF` is able to use plugins. In order to enable it to print HTML, you have to include certain plugins and therefore have to do the following:
Go to https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF and download the latest Version.

Include the following Scripts in your project:

```
jspdf.js
jspdf.plugin.from_html.js
jspdf.plugin.split_text_to_size.js
jspdf.plugin.standard_fonts_metrics.js
```

If you want to ignore certain elements, you have to mark them with an ID, which you can then ignore in a special element handler of jsPDF. Therefore your HTML should look like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p id="ignorePDF">don't print this to pdf</p>
    <div>
      <p><font size="3" color="red">print this to pdf</font></p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you use the following JavaScript code to open the created PDF in a PopUp:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();          
var elementHandler = {
  '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
    return true;
  }
};
var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
doc.fromHTML(
    source,
    15,
    15,
    {
      'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
    }
);

doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
```

Answer (score 0):

When I open my PDF, I have a white page, and the PDF keeps on loading:
[image]

Here is my code:
component.show.ts

```
        import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { BasicRequestsService } from '../../../../../core/services/basic-requests.service';
    import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { Observable, forkJoin } from 'rxjs';
    import { FormsModule, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
    import { DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
    import * as jsPDF from 'jspdf';
    import { ElementRef, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
    import { ToastsService } from '../../../../../core/services/toasts.service';
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
      selector: 'app-tools-billing-invoices-show',
      templateUrl: './show.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./show.component.scss', '../invoices.component.scss']
    })


export class InvoicesShowComponent implements OnInit {
      endpoint = '/tools/billing/billers/';
      billerId;
      billerData;
      invoiceId;
      invoice;
      invoiceUpdated;
      invoiceLines;
      invoiceForm;
      clientData;
      symbol;
      invoiceTotal = {taxExcluded: 0, tax: 0, taxIncluded: 0};
      date: Date;
      constructor(
        private basicRequestsService: BasicRequestsService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private toasts: ToastsService,
        ) { }


createPdf(): void {
        var doc = new jsPDF();
        var elementHandler = {
          '#ignorePDF': function (element, renderer) {
            return true;
          }
        };
        var source = window.document.getElementsByTagName("invoice-preview-box")[0];
        doc.fromHTML(
          source,
          15,
          15,
          {
            'width': 180,'elementHandlers': elementHandler
          });
        doc.output("dataurlnewwindow");
      }
    }
```

Here is my HTML

```
 <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="createPdf()">Generate PDF</button>  

<div class="col-xl-9 invoice-preview-box" tag="invoice-preview-box" id="invoice-preview-box"> Hello World, here is MY PDF </div>
```